# How to add links to each table entry using PrimeVue's DataTable component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, primevue

The PrimeVue library does not support this by default. The Table currently looks like [this](https://prnt.sc/111skv3) .

This is my array of products:

```
products: [
        {brand: "Volkswagen", year: 2012, color: "Orange", vin: "dsad231ff", url: "linkToSite"},
        {brand: "Audi", year: 2011, color: "Black", vin: "gwregre345", url: "linkToSite"},
        {brand: "Renault", year: 2005, color: "Gray", "vin": "h354htr", url: "linkToSite"},
   ]
```

This is the default PrimeVue DT column setup:

```
columns: [
            {field: 'brand', header: 'Brand'},
            {field: 'year', header: 'Year'},
            {field: 'color', header: 'Color'},
            {field: 'vin', header: 'Vin'}
        ]
```

This is my template code:

```
<DataTable :value="products">
    <Column v-for="col of columns" :field="col.field" :header="col.header" :key="col.field"></Column>
</DataTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `<template #body="slotProps">` to customize the appearance of cells in a `<Column>`.

```
<DataTable ...>
  <Column field="brand" header="Brand">
    <template #body="slotProps">
      <a :href="slotProps.data.url" v-text="slotProps.data.brand" />
    </template>
  </Column>  
  ...
</DataTable>
```

More examples in [docs](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/showcase/#/datatable/templating).

Inside your v-for (I haven't tested this, but it should work):

```
  <Column v-for="col of columns"
         :field="col.field"
         :header="col.header"
         :key="col.field">
    <template #body="slotProps" v-if="col.field === 'brand'">
      <a :href="slotProps.data.url" v-text="slotProps.data.brand" />
    </template>
  </Column>
```

If, for some reason, it doesn't work, please create a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using codesandbox.io or similar, with what you currently have, and I'll have a look into why it doesn't work for you.