# PrimeVue Datatable adding a dynamic router-link to each field in a column

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, primevue

I am using PrimeVue version 13.15 Datatable to display my displays information from a GraphQL query with the fields `['id', 'name', 'notes']`

```
    <DataTable :value="clients" responsiveLayout="scroll">
    <Column field="name" header="Name">
    </Column>
    <Column field="notes" header="Notes"></Column>
    </DataTable>

    //query
    const { result } = useQuery(getClients)
    const clients = computed(() => result.value?.clients ?? [])
```

This code works fine, but I want to link the column with "name" to another page in routes that take an id:

```
const routes = [ 
  {
    path: '/clients/:id',
    name: 'client_profile',

    component: () => import('../views/client_profile.vue')
  },
]
```

Since the router works like this for links:

```
<p v-for="c in clients" :key="c.id">
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'client_profile', params: { id:'c.id' }}"> {{c.name}} 
       </router-link>
</p>
```

I tried using slots as shown using [hard link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66910256/how-to-add-links-to-each-table-entry-using-primevues-datatable-component)s but it does not work. There is no information in the documentation on how to do this so far:

```
    <DataTable :value="clients" responsiveLayout="scroll">
    <Column field="name" header="Name">
       <router-link :to="{ name: 'client_profile', params: { id:'slotProps.data.id' }}"> {{slotProps.data.name}} 
       </router-link>
    </Column>
    <Column field="notes" header="Notes"></Column>
    </DataTable>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. You can add in a template inside the column section and add the router link like this:

```
<DataTable :value="clients" responsiveLayout="scroll">
<Column field="name" header="Name">
        <template #body="{data}">
           <router-link :to="{ name: 'client_profile', params: { id:'data.id' }}"> {{data.name}} 
           </router-link>
        </template>
</Column>
<Column field="notes" header="Notes"></Column>
</DataTable>
```